# “In no time” - choose the correct verbal construction

Tags: present-tense, future-tense

Why do we have to choose the future continuous construction for the following sentence?

> “The doctor says I will be feeling better in no time.”

Can’t I use the present continuous cpnstruction?

> “The doctor says I am feeling better in no time.”

Comment: Would you see a doctor when you are feeling better? No, that -will- happen in the future.

Comment: Yes, you may, and the use of this construction in this context is to express profound confidence and cheer at the doctor's prognosis.

Comment: @green_ideas “you may”? So I can use the present continuous?

Comment: Yes, you can and may. But I do not know your level of English, so whether to recommend that you yourself use it is another question.